# mvc3 how do I clear the submitted form values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ajax.beginform

I am new to asp .net mvc3. I am trying to create a failrly simple blog comments section.

I have a CommentsViewModel

```
public class CommentsViewModel
{
    public CommentModel NewComment { get; set; }
    public IList<CommentModel> CommentsList { get; set; }
}
```

The corresponding view is like

```
<div id="CommentsArea">
@Html.Partial("CommentsList", Model.CommentsList)
</div>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create",
                   "Comment",
                   new { id = Model.NewComment.detailsId, comment = Model.NewComment },
                   new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "CommentsArea" ,
                                     HttpMethod = "Post",
                                     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace}))
{
<div class="display-label">Add Comment</div>
<div class="display-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.NewComment.Body)
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Post" />
}
```

Now when user enters Post button I want the "CommentsArea" to be updated with the new comments list and also the form values to be cleared with empty text.

Here is the Post method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(int id, CommentModel newcomment)
    {
        var newsItem = m_db.NewsList.Single(news => news.Id == id);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newcomment.Body))
        {
                newcomment.detailsId = id;
                newsItem.Comments.Add(newcomment);
                m_db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return PartialView("CommentsList", newsItem.Comments);
    }
```

Now when user clicks Post button the list gets updated properly,
but the form values are not cleared. i.e. if I posted a comment "New Comments", the comments list gets updated with "New Comments", but that text remains inside the edit box of the form.

How do I clear that text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just call a js function on success of form submit.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create",
                   "Comment",
                   new { id = Model.NewComment.detailsId, comment = Model.NewComment },
                   new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess="ClearInput", HttpMethod = "Post",}))
```

on js function render create view again

```
function ClearInput(){
      //call action for render create view
      $.ajax({})
}
```

Comment: this link also explains: http://www.gbogea.com/2008/11/26/ajax-beginform-clear-form-after-submit